# creating a txt file on sd card but i cant find it

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I want to create a textfile on my sdcard. I found lots of codesamples and tried them. None of them responded any Exception so i expected them to work, but when I was exploring my sdcard, I could not find a textfile. 
Here is the attempt I am trying:

```
 try {
            File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

            File myFile = new File(sdcard,"text.txt");
            myFile.createNewFile();

            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
            OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter =
                    new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
            myOutWriter.append(encodedString); // this is a long string
            myOutWriter.close();
            fOut.close();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "written to: "+myFile.getAbsolutePath(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Here is what the Toast is telling me:
What I expect: "written to: /sdcard/text.txt"
What I get: "written to: /storage/emulated/0/text.txt"

Why is the app not saving the textfile as intended onto the sdcard and what do I have to change in order to make it do it?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6988134/3033386

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getExternalStorageDirectory() does not necessary return /sdcard directory. See here [Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory does not return the path to the removable storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049114/environment-getexternalstoragedirectory-does-not-return-the-path-to-the-removabl)

Comment: I think my problem is here, okay. Can u add what I have to change in the code in order to have the file saved on the sdcard?

Comment: I haven't try but I think /proc/mounts shell command will returns list of mounted storages. Process procmount = Runtime.getRuntime.exec("/proc/mounts"); and parse data returned by Process.getOutputStream()